# Uma duvida sobre o numero 0 em javascript

Tags: javascript

Queria entender uma coisa, por que quando eu coloco o numero `0` na frente na hora de imprimir no `console`
o numero sai totalmente diferente, mas quando eu não coloco o numero `0` no começo o numero aparece normal?

```js
 var numero = 066233;
 var numero2 = 66233;
 console.log(numero,numero2)
```

Comment: Só por curiosidade, se fizer `var numero = 068233;` deixa de ser um octal pois o digito `8` faz com que o lexicógrafo interprete o número como decimal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Números começados em 0 são interpretados como Octal.

Inicio Diferente de zero = Decimal (base 10, números "normais")

Inicio 0 = Octal (base 8)

Inicio 0x = Hexadecimal (base 16)

Comment: É Octal mesmo, editei já na resposta. Usei o nome errado em pt...